# How to access state properties to store from out side component in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have one component it has some state like `value: false` and I want to access that state to the reducer, how I can access it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

class Parent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {

            validate:true
    }
}

render() {
  return (
        <div>
            hi
            <Child />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

export default Parent

```
 const RootReducer = (state, action)=>{
    switch (action.type){
        case "ADD" :
            return{
                ...state,
            }
            default:
                return state;
    }

}
export default RootReducer;
```

Comment: create `mapStateToProp` and then  `export default connect(mapStateToProp)(Parent)` in parent

Comment: Or you can pass the connected props as a function params